# Finding the time difference in sql server by only time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a train database in which I have many train details with columns like `Train_No`, `Station_Name`, `Arrival_Time`, `Depature_Time` , `Source_Station` and `Destination_Station`. What I need is the time difference which I am able to find using `DATEDIFF(MI,Starttime,EndTime)` but I need a scenario like this if a train starts from a particular station at `13:15 PM` and Reach the Departure Station at `13:45 PM`, so if I find the time difference it will be `30 Minutes`, But in my case it should show me `1470 Minutes` because the Train reached the Destination on other day but I have only the time no date to find this. for clear understanding I am attaching the sample data
"Data:

```
Train No.,Train Name,islno,station Code,Station Name,Arrival time,Departure time,Distance,Source Station Code,Source Station Name,Destination station Code,Destination Station Name,Distance
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,1,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,'00:00:00','19:50:00',0,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,64
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,2,LNL ,LONAVALA       ,'20:43:00','20:45:00',64,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,28
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,3,KJT ,KARJAT         ,'21:28:00','21:30:00',92,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,47
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,4,KYN ,KALYAN JN      ,'22:17:00','22:20:00',139,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,25
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,5,BIRD,BHIWANDI ROAD  ,'22:48:00','22:50:00',164,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,27
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,6,BSR ,VASAI ROAD     ,'23:45:00','23:50:00',191,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,72
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,7,DRD ,DAHANU ROAD    ,'01:08:00','01:10:00',263,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,51
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,8,VAPI,VAPI           ,'01:43:00','01:45:00',314,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,24
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,9,BL  ,VALSAD         ,'02:11:00','02:13:00',338,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,39
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,10,NVS ,NAVSARI        ,'03:01:00','03:03:00',377,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,29
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,11,ST  ,SURAT          ,'03:50:00','03:55:00',406,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,59
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,12,BH  ,BHARUCH JN     ,'04:39:00','04:41:00',465,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,70
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,13,BRC ,VADODARA JN    ,'05:40:00','05:45:00',535,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,36
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,14,ANND,ANAND JN       ,'06:19:00','06:21:00',571,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,18
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,15,ND  ,NADIAD JN      ,'06:39:00','06:41:00',589,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,43
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,16,MAN ,MANINAGAR      ,'07:23:00','07:25:00',632,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,3
'11096',AHIMSA EXPRESS ,17,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,'07:45:00','00:00:00',635,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,-635
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,1,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,'00:00:00','23:30:00',0,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,20
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,2,AWY ,ALUVA          ,'23:51:00','23:53:00',20,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,55
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,3,TCR ,THRISUR        ,'00:38:00','00:41:00',75,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,32
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,4,SRR ,SHORANUR JN    ,'01:30:00','01:35:00',107,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,45
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,5,TIR ,TIRUR          ,'02:14:00','02:16:00',152,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,41
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,6,CLT ,KOZHIKODE      ,'03:05:00','03:10:00',193,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,69
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,7,TLY ,THALASSERY     ,'04:02:00','04:03:00',262,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,21
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,8,CAN ,KANNUR         ,'04:35:00','04:40:00',283,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,33
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,9,PAY ,PAYYANUR       ,'05:08:00','05:10:00',316,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,29
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,10,KZE ,KANHANGAD      ,'05:35:00','05:37:00',345,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,23
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,11,KGQ ,KASARAGOD      ,'05:53:00','05:55:00',368,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,51
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,12,MAJN,MANGALORE JN   ,'07:05:00','07:15:00',419,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,36
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,13,MULK,MULKI          ,'07:44:00','07:45:00',455,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,46
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,14,UD  ,UDUPI          ,'08:40:00','08:42:00',501,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,44
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,15,KUDA,KUNDAPURA      ,'09:28:00','09:30:00',545,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,69
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,16,BTJL,BHATKAL        ,'10:20:00','10:22:00',614,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,21
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,17,MRDW,MURDESHWAR     ,'10:40:00','10:42:00',635,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,37
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,18,HNA ,HONNAVAR       ,'11:10:00','11:12:00',672,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,19
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,19,KT  ,KUMTA          ,'11:40:00','11:42:00',691,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,27
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,20,GOK ,GOKARNA ROAD   ,'12:00:00','12:02:00',718,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,50
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,21,KAWR,KARWAR         ,'12:50:00','12:52:00',768,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,82
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,22,MAO ,MADGAON        ,'14:05:00','14:25:00',850,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,16
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,23,SVM ,SANVERDAM CHUCH,'14:38:00','14:40:00',866,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,18
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,24,QLM ,KULEM          ,'15:05:00','15:10:00',884,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,59
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,25,CLR ,CASTLE ROCK    ,'16:05:00','16:10:00',943,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,24
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,26,LD  ,LONDA JN       ,'16:48:00','16:50:00',967,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,51
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,27,BGM ,BELGAUM        ,'18:55:00','19:00:00',1018,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,58
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,28,GPB ,GHATPRABHA     ,'19:58:00','20:00:00',1076,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,80
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,29,MRJ ,MIRAJ JN       ,'22:55:00','23:00:00',1156,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,7
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,30,SLI ,SANGLI         ,'23:12:00','23:15:00',1163,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,68
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,31,KRD ,KARAD          ,'00:12:00','00:15:00',1231,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,59
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,32,STR ,SATARA         ,'01:07:00','01:10:00',1290,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,145
'11098',POORNA EXPRESS ,33,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,'05:05:00','00:00:00',1435,ERS ,ERNAKULAM JN   ,PUNE,PUNE JN        ,-1435
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,1,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,'00:00:00','16:55:00',0,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,68
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,2,MSH ,MAHESANA JN    ,'17:58:00','18:00:00',68,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,65
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,3,PNU ,PALANPUR JN    ,'19:36:00','19:38:00',133,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,53
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,4,ABR ,ABU ROAD       ,'21:00:00','21:12:00',186,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,99
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,5,FA  ,FALNA          ,'22:29:00','22:31:00',285,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,66
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,6,MJ  ,MARWAR JN      ,'23:30:00','23:32:00',351,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,88
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,7,BER ,BEAWAR         ,'00:57:00','00:59:00',439,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,52
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,8,AII ,AJMER JN       ,'02:00:00','02:10:00',491,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,135
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,9,JP  ,JAIPUR         ,'04:05:00','04:15:00',626,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,187
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,10,BTE ,BHARATPUR JN   ,'06:48:00','06:50:00',813,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,54
'12548',AGRA SUPER FAST,11,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,'08:20:00','00:00:00',867,ADI ,AHMEDABAD JN   ,AF  ,AGRA FORT      ,-867"
```

So if you see the above data, lets take if a person start from `PUNE JN` in Train No `11096` and wants to depart at `SURAT` I need to find the time difference for this how can I do that?

Comment: The question of how you are storing the times (`10:40:00`, etc.) as varchar or something else aside, how do you plan to measure time for a train journey that, for example, started at 10pm on on day (22 hours), and arrived the next morning (5 hours) ?

Comment: Do you know which trains are departing and arriving on different days?

Comment: To make your table structure more flexible and for easy querying, don't save the timings. Save the elapsed minutes and the start time of the train.

Comment: It's very difficult to match your narrative to your sample data (do you really think *all* of the columns are relevant to your question, could you not trim this down to just the *relevant* parts), since there doesn't appear to be any values in your sample data that have a time of 13:15

Answer (score 4):

You could for example create a view, that has a column with something like this:

```
select 
  sum(Days) over (partition by [Train No] order by Distance) as Days, *
from (
  select
    case when lag([Arrival time]) over (partition by [Train No] order by Distance) > [Arrival time] 
      then 1 else 0 end as Days, *
  from
    yourtable
) X
```

This checks the rows where `Arrival time` has decreased, so it must be a new day and then adds 1 to the column. The outer select then does a running total for the days, so it will then add up all the days. Just use then that column with your date calculations.

Didn't test this, but it should work fine.

Comment: the above query giving me only 1 day or 0 days by comparing with the previous value but in my case ,if you see my data if a person selects `Lonaval` at `Station_Name`  and he wants to go to `Ahmedabad ` I am talking about the train no: `11096` then I need to find the time to travel in Minutes , so In the above scenario the `Departure Time`  from `Lonavala` is `20:45:00` and the `Arrival Time` for `Ahmedabad Jn` is `7:45:00` so it should give me 660 minutes as Travel Time , how can I get this

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server 2012+ you can look at `LEAD` and `LAG`. Very handsome if you need a following or previous row.

To your question:

If there are connections which might be correct with more than 24 hours you'll have to store some kind of "approximate duration" (or at least a *isMoreThan24Hours* indication) in a side table (use a `CROSS JOIN` with all your stations and average the existing data. The rest is manual work.

If you are sure, that there is no connection that last longer you should be happy with JamesZ's answer...